# EF query 'string StartsWith any string' in DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've got following working code, which queries all products having an ATC code equal to one specified in the filter list. `filter.AtcCodes` is `public ICollection<string>? AtcCodes { get; set; }` and `product.AtcCode` is `public string? AtcCode { get; set; }`.

```
if (filter.AtcCodes != null)
{
   query = query.Where(product => filter.AtcCodes.Contains(product.AtcCode!));
}
```

EF translates it correctly to SQL `WHERE [v].[AtcCode] IN (N'G04', N'L04')`.

Now I have to change the query to not be equal but `StartsWith`. I expected both of the below ways to work, but neither of these expressions can be translated by EF:

```
query = query.Where(product => filter.AtcCodes.Any(atcCode => product.AtcCode!.StartsWith(atcCode)));
query = query.Where(product => filter.AtcCodes.Any(atcCode => EF.Functions.Like(product.AtcCode, $"{atcCode}%")));
```

I've also tried this approach, which is being translated correctly and works

```
query = query.Where(product => product.AtcCode!.StartsWith(filter.AtcCodes.ElementAt(0)) || product.AtcCode!.StartsWith(filter.AtcCodes.ElementAt(1)));
```

But I don't see a way to support 1-n entries. That's where `Any()` would be great, if it could be translated.

As a workaround (I'd like to get rid of), this part of the filtering is now being done in memory like this

```
var result = await query.Select(product => new {product.ProductNr, product.AtcCode})
                        .ToListAsync();

if (filter.AtcCodes != null) {
   result = result.Where(product => filter.AtcCodes.Any(atcCode => product.AtcCode!.StartsWith(atcCode)))
                  .ToList();
}

return result.Select(arg => arg.ProductNr).ToList();
```

How can I tell EF to execute this search in DB?

Comment: Consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). You would need to use an extension to create an `Expression` tree representing `||` sub-expressions each with `StartsWith`.

Comment: @NetMage I'll have a look at LINQKit but was hoping this was possible with EF out of the box.

Comment: Only if you are willing to re-create a small portion of LINQKit in your code.